# How to handle exceptions caused by nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `quiz`, which has many `questions` models. I want to add some kind of esception handling so that when the user types in a wrong `quiz_id` in the URL, an error page would be rendered.

I wrote some helper methods in my `QuestionsController` to handle the exceptions:

```
private
def render_error(message)
    @error_message = message
    render 'error'
end

def active_quizzes_safe
    active_quizzes = Quiz.active_quizzes(current_user.id)
    render_error('Sorry! The request is invalid! Please log in again!') if active_quizzes.nil?
    active_quizzes
end


def active_quiz_safe(quiz_id)
    active_quiz = active_quizzes_safe.where(id: quiz_id).first
    render_error('The quiz does not exist or you are not allowed to take this quiz!') if active_quiz.blank?
    active_quiz
end
```

And here is the action in `QuestionsController` which has problems:

```
def show_quiz
  if current_user
    @quiz = active_quiz_safe(params[:quiz_id])
    @questions = @quiz.questions
  end
end
```

So if the `:quiz_id` in the URL `localhost:3000/MY_URL/:quiz_id` is not correct(that is, a record cannot be found), an error page should be rendered by the `render_error` mothod. However, when I tired a wrong `:quiz_id`, I got `undefined method 'questions' for nil:NilClass`. I guess this is because of the `@questions = @quiz.questions` in `show_quiz` method.

However, is the execution supposed to halt after the `render_error` action, which is before `@questions = @quiz.questions`? Why `@questions = @quiz.questions` is executed anyway?

In addtion, are there any standard ways to handle nil:NilClass errors like this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your `public/404.html, public/422.html and public/500.html` files. Rails will automatically redirects if error occurs anyway. So I think you don't need to manually handle exceptions, except you have specific case. To test and view this error pages run application in production `bundle exec rails s RAILS_ENV=production`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `render` method does not halt the action. So you should carefully design your action to ensure that you return immediately after rendering. Like this:

```
def show_quiz
  if current_user
    active_quizzes = Quiz.active_quizzes(current_user.id)
    if active_quizzes.nil?
      render_error('Sorry! The request is invalid! Please log in again!')
    else
      @quiz = active_quizzes_safe.where(id: quiz_id).first
      if @quiz.blank?
        render_error('The quiz does not exist or you are not allowed to take this quiz!')
      else
        @questions = @quiz.questions
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But in this case, I think it's better to use some exception control, like this:

```
def show_quiz
  if current_user
    active_quizzes = Quiz.active_quizzes(current_user.id)
    @quiz = active_quizzes_safe.find(quiz_id)
    @questions = @quiz.questions
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render_error 'The quiz does not exist or you are not allowed to take this quiz!'
end
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! So seems like exception control is the only "standard way" to handle this? I still have to write many other actions, so it means I have to add the same codes to every action, which is not DRY. Just don't know if there is a way to keep the controller "skinny"..